# How can I configure a hook with a lambda? (Saving parameters to use in lambdas)

Tags: emacs, hook

I am currently trying to set up a C++ hook for setting shortcuts to compile different projects and I have the following code:

```
(defun configure-proj (proj key)
    (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
              (function (lambda ()
                          (local-set-key (kbd (concatenate 'string key " u")) (lambda () (compile-unit-tests proj)))
                          (local-set-key (kbd (concatenate 'string key " d")) (lambda () (compile-debug proj)))
                          (local-set-key (kbd (concatenate 'string key " r")) (lambda () (compile-balanced proj)))
                          (local-set-key (kbd (concatenate 'string key " i")) (lambda () (compile-func-interactive proj "balanced" "11")))
                          (local-set-key (kbd (concatenate 'string key " c")) 'clean-all)))))

(configure-proj "Proj name" "<f4>")
```

The error states that there is a `File mode specification error: (void-variable key)`. I know that the error in my code is that the key parameter from `configure-proj` is not being copied when the hook is being created, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Edit: Forgot to show how I run `configure-proj`.

Comment: Activate lexical binding in your buffer, so that "key" is a lexical binding to your function parameter; also, local-set-key wants commands, not functions; your anonymous lambda functions are going to give you an error, unless you add `(interactive)` after the lambda-list. Prefer "concat" instead of "concatenate 'string"

Comment: Not related to your lambda problem, but maybe to your project configuration problem: https://github.com/ReanGD/emacs-multi-compile

Answer (score 2):

As explained by coredump, the problem is that your config file is not using lexical scoping.  So add `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` somewhere on the first line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to enable lexical-binding for the whole library, then you could alternatively use a workaround like:

```el
(defun configure-proj (proj key)
  (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
            `(lambda ()
               (local-set-key ,(kbd (concatenate 'string key " u")) (lambda () (interactive) (compile-unit-tests proj)))
               (local-set-key ,(kbd (concatenate 'string key " d")) (lambda () (interactive) (compile-debug proj)))
               (local-set-key ,(kbd (concatenate 'string key " r")) (lambda () (interactive) (compile-balanced proj)))
               (local-set-key ,(kbd (concatenate 'string key " i")) (lambda () (interactive) (compile-func-interactive proj "balanced" "11")))
               (local-set-key ,(kbd (concatenate 'string key " c")) 'clean-all))))
```